# Makefile: crt1.o: In function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'

Tags: c, makefile

When I compile my makefile, I encounter this problem:

```
gcc   parser.tab.o   -o parser.tab
/usr/lib/../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
parser.tab.o: In function `yyparse':
parser.tab.c:(.text+0x2c3): undefined reference to `yylex'
parser.tab.c:(.text+0x3f5): undefined reference to `execute'
parser.tab.c:(.text+0x82b): undefined reference to `yyerror'
parser.tab.c:(.text+0x947): undefined reference to `yyerror'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [parser.tab] Error 1
```

Here is my make file:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -lreadline 
PROGS = d8sh parser.tab executor lexer


all: $(PROGS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(PROGS) *.tmp

d8sh: d8sh.o

d8sh.o: executor.h lexer.h

executor.o: command.h

lexer.o: parser.tab.h

parser.tab.o: command.h
```

Only d8sh.c has a main function. Can anyone figure out what the problem is?

Comment: I assume you only want one executable with all the object files in it? Then just have that one in PROGS, not all of them, and define what objects go to the binary. Now make thinks you have four separate executables.

Comment: The command line should be `gcc -c  parser.tab.o   -o parser.tab` as you are only compiling, not linking it. The rule for `parser.tab.o` should be `gcc -c parser.tab.o   -o parser.tab` or something like  `$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@`

Comment: @pablo: the rule for `parser.tab.o` should have `-o parser.tab.o`. It certainly should not have `parser.tab.o` as an input.

Comment: regarding: `CFLAGS = -lreadline`  the library `readline` will not have its' contents linked into the executable. because `CFLAGS` is placed early in the link statement  Suggest: `LFLAGS = -lreadline`  as the `LFLAGS is placed toward the end of the link statement and the linker performs its' operations from left to right and when a library is early in the line, there are no unresolved symbols to look for.

Comment: regarding: `PROGS = d8sh parser.tab executor lexer`  there is only one executable to be made, not 4 executables.  Suggest changing that statement to: `PROGS = d8sh`